# AWS ACM(Certificate Manager) priority sequence

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, subdomain, amazon-certificate-manager

1. In AWS ACM i have a public certificate which covers **example.com** and ***.example.com**
2. Our client require a unique/separate certificate for the subdomain **test.example.com**
3. To solve this i have create another ACM public certificate with domain name as **test.example.com**
4. Added subdomain "A" certificate with domain name as **test.example.com** under route53 records in hosted zone for **example.com** domain

**Question** :- In above scenario which certificate will have more priority the one created with domain name **test.example.com** or ***.example.com**

**Follow up** :- How do i validate the certs(to make sure which cert the domain name is using currently).

Answer (score 0):

More specific one should always be used, which is `test.example.com`. You can test that you can use any browser, or curl if you want:

```
curl -Ivv https://test.example.com 2>&1 | grep "subject"
```

should give something as the following when cert for `test.example.com` is used:

```
subject: CN=test.example.com
```

otherwise it would be:

```
subject: CN=*.example.com
```

Comment: Current certificates should have names in the SAN extension, the subject is more and more ignored by browsers.